# Yeastless Rusk in breading for deep frying

Tags: deep-frying, breadcrumbs, breading

I recently bought a load of yeastless rusk for sausagemaking purposes (if you're unsure what yeastless rusk is, I purchased it [here](https://www.weschenfelder.co.uk/yeastless-bread-rusk.html), where you can see a photo and brief description). It came in a *much* larger quantity than I need for these sausagemaking purposes. Obviously I could use the rest for making other sausages, but I've been thinking about other uses.

Yeastless rusk is used in sausagemaking as an alternative to the more traditional breadcrumbs (because it absorbs water better, see this question [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/114124/yeast-in-sausage)), so my mind went straight to other instances where I'd use breadcrumbs. Stuffing is a pretty obvious one and based on its advantages over breadcrumbs ought to work pretty well.

Less clearcut to me is the case of breading food for deep-frying.

Is yeastless rusk likely to work as a sub for breadcrumbs for breading food for deep-frying, or is the slightly different texture, and greater absorption of water likely to cause issues?

Answer (score 0):

My immediate thought is that the superior absorbency would make it work quite well as a breading or pre-dust, since it would stick to the surface of the meat and be less likely to slough off after cooking as moisture built up. I haven’t tried it, though.

Comment: I think my main concern is that it might end up as more of a lumpy batter than a breading, if it behaves a bit too similarly to flour, and not similarly enough to breadcrumbs. I guess I'll have to test it and report back!

Comment: @Tristan being baked, it won't behave like raw flour.  I think it will be as suitable as dry breadcrumbs, though possibly crunchier